# Validate form field using function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to validate the form fields by creating my own jquery function so that I can just call it anywhere using only few lines, I have below code but don't know why its not working:

```
(function($){
        $.fn.validate_form = function(options){
            var defaults = {
                valid_class: "no_error",
                error_class: "form_errors"
            };
            var new_options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function(){
                var this_value = $(this).val();
                if(!this_value)
                {
                    $(this).removeClass(new_options.valid_class);
                    $(this).addClass(new_options.error_class);
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).removeClass(new_options.error_class);
                    $(this).addClass(new_options.valid_class);
                }
            });
        };
})(jQuery);

$("#service_title").validate_form();
```

Here "service_title" is an ID of a text field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify "not working"? Get any JS-errors?

Comment: I am sorry guys I didn't explain the term "not working", here I am not getting any JS error, my control is not going inside "return this.each(function(){}" don't know the reason why.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there are whitespace characters which you're missing, I'd pass the field's value to `$.trim`:

```
var this_value = $.trim($(this).val());
```